# supported dictionary type: smtp.gmail.com

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, docker

I'm trying to setup `postfix` inside a Docker container. On startup I'm running the following setup script:

```
# Install postfix/mailutils with configuration options
echo "postfix postfix/mailname string $MAILSERVER:587" | debconf-set-selections
echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -yqq postfix
apt-get install -yqq mailutils

# Setup credentials for SMTP server
mkdir -p /etc/postfix/sasl
touch /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "[$MAILSERVER]:587 $EMAIL_USER:$EMAIL_PASSWORD" >> /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
chown -R postfix:postfix /etc/postfix
chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd

# Create postfix configuration 
echo "relayhost = [$MAILSERVER]:587" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "smtp_use_tls = yes" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "debug_peer_list = $MAILSERVER" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "debug_peer_level = 3" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf

# Reload postfix for new configurations to take effect
postfix reload
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

After running the script I end up with the following at the end of my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
# Use gmail
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
debug_peer_list=smtp.gmail.com
debug_peer_level=3
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I have confirmed that `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` exist but I keep getting:

```
postfix/bounce[1052]: error: unsupported dictionary type: smtp.gmail.com
```

Note: I have seen questions with similar titles but the solutions posted haven't helped with my setup.

Comment: Crossposting on unix.SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397278/88119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue but I'm not sure what caused it in the first place.

During the install process the gmail SMTP server was added to the value `mydestination` in `main.cf`.

I ended up running the following script in my `Dockerfile` to make fix the value:

```
sed -i '/mydestination =/d' /etc/postfix/main.cf
echo "mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Here, you are using Berkeley DB as a [Postfix lookup table type](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types):

> `hash`
>
> An indexed file type based on hashing. This is available only on
>   systems with support for Berkeley DB databases. Public database files
>   are created with the `postmap(1)` or `postalias(1)` command, and private
>   databases are maintained by Postfix daemons. The database name as used
>   in `hash:table` is the database file name without the `.db` suffix.

Therefore, the existence of `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` is not as relevant as the existence of `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db`, generated with `postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`. However, if you were missing that file, I believe you should instead have an error telling it directly.

It might be that your Postfix is missing Berkeley DB support. On Debian, the default `postfix` package is built with the support, and you can check whether it has it using `postconf -m`. If the list doesn't include `hash` and `btree`, you are missing the support. Then, for more information please consult [Postfix Berkeley DB Howto](http://www.postfix.org/DB_README.html).

Comment: Thanks, useful information. I can confirm I have `hash` and `btree` when running`postconf -m`